# Imported Vue component only registered on Webpack hot reload

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js, webpack-hot-middleware

I am building a project from the `vue-cli` webpack boilerplate. I have a single file Vue component, `Foo.vue`, inside a `components` directory which also contains an `index.js` file which imports and exports `Foo`:

```
// components/index.js
import Foo from './Foo.vue'
export {
  Foo
}
```

In another component `Bar.vue`, I am importing `Foo` and registering it locally.

```
// Bar.vue
<template>
  <foo></foo>
</template>
<script>
  import { Foo } from 'components'

  export default {
  name: 'bar',
  components: {
    Foo
    }
  }
  </script>
  <style></style>
```

On page load, the console logs the error

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <foo> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

When I try to `console.log(Foo)` after importing, it outputs `undefined`.

**However,**
If I make any modification to `Bar.vue` and save, Webpack's hot-reload kicks in, the page refreshes, and `<foo>` is rendered correctly. Moreover, `console.log(Foo)` now shows me the entire Vue object in the console.

**Also,** `<foo>` will *always* render correctly if I import it with

```
import Foo from 'components/Foo'
```

What is going on here?? Is the ES6 module syntax handled differently on initial load vs hot reloading?

*Side note:*

Here are a couple more details about my actual project that I did not think were relevant to this bug, but I'll include here just in case.

- `Bar.vue` also lives in the `components` directory.
- `Bar.vue` itself is imported by another Vue component.
- Webpack version: 2.2.1
- Babel core version: 6.22.1

Let me know if there are any other config files or whatever to help diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

What it did work for me was:

```
// Bar.vue
<template>
    <foo></foo>
</template>
<script>
  // alternative syntax for import 
  // import Foo from '@/components/Foo'
  import { Foo } from 'components'

  export default {
    name: 'bar',
    components: {
        'Foo': Foo
    }
  }
  </script>
  <style></style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but maybe my answer can still help.

TL;DR - In my case it was a circular dependency caused by the order of re-exports in the `index.js` file. I found the solution here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/es6-imports-from-index-file-for-component-causes-unknown-custom-element-error/27983

I ran into this issue too and it turned out that I was creating a circular dependency within my `index.js` file.

src/components/**Foo.vue**:

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Foo'
}
</script>
```

src/components/**Bar.vue**:

```
<template>
  <foo></foo>
</template>

<script>
import { Foo } from './'

export default {
  name: 'Bar',
  components: { Foo }
}
</script>
```

src/components/**index.js**

```js
export { default as Bar } from './Bar'  // imports foo from index but foo 'has not been exported from index jet'
export { default as Foo } from './Foo'  // exporting foo from index but 'to late'
```

changing the order as follows:

src/components/**index.js** (the new version)

```js
export { default as Foo } from './Foo'  // exporting foo from index - no problem
export { default as Bar } from './Bar'  // imports foo from index and foo 'is already present'
```

solved my problem.

**Im not quite sure if `'has not been exported from index jet'`, `'to late'` and `'is already present'` are valid terms here but they describe the problem very well in my opinion. Still be careful to not cause misunderstandings when using these terms!!**